# Category name is getting passed instead of code on PLP

Tags: java, debugging, sap-commerce-cloud

On opening the *PLP/Category page*, I am getting the error:

> Category with code abc not found! (Active session catalogversions:
> xyz)

Interestingly, the `category name` is showing as `abc` instead of the `category code`. Therefore, I am assuming that the `category name` is getting passed instead of the `category code`.

This error is coming from-

```
Category with code '" + code + "' not found! (Active session catalogversions: " + getCatalogVersionsString() + ") which is in -
```

1. DefaultCommerceCategoryService
2. DefaultCategoryService

I have applied *loggers* in both of these classes (after overriding) but I am still getting the error. Is there some class that I am missing?